# preg_replace two arrows with space

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a string which has '> >'.  I am trying to replace 'test > >' with 'test >>>>'.

str_replace doesnt replace anything, so I have tried using:

```
$string = preg_replace("/[\>\ \>]/",">>>>", $string);
```

But this replaces all spaces in the string as well as the arrows.

So the string ends up like `'test>>>>>>>>'` instead of `'test >>>>'`

Comment: "str_replace doesnt replace anything" - yes it does. Indeed that it is explicitly what it is intended to do. So while I endorse your taking a different approach, when that different approach failed, you really should have gone back to your original code and asked a question about that: the syntax of str_replace is much simpler and more than capable of solving the task here. Regular expressions are very useful but *very powerful, difficult to understand and easy to get wrong*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/[\>\ \>]/` regex matches a single char that is either `>`, a space or `>` and `preg_replace` replaces multiple occurrences (by default).

If there are no specific context requirements, you may use a `str_replace` like

```
$s = "test > >";
echo str_replace('> >', '>>>>', $s);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/PmBaQc)

If you want to only replace `> >` not followed or preceded with `>`, you may try

```
echo preg_replace("/(?<!> )> >(?!\s*>)/",">>>>", $s);
```

See [another PHP demo](https://ideone.com/7FybkA) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G9YZ3n/1).

The `(?<!> )` lookbehind will fail the match if the `>` is preceded with `>` and a space, and `(?!\s*>)` lookahead will fail the match if here are 0+ whitespaces followed with `>` after `> >`.

Comment: Your answers work, but not with the string im using, its a problem with my string

Comment: the string is taken from an array and when printed i can see '> >' but str_replace or preg_replace wont find the arrows with a space, is there a way to clean the string before I try this?

Comment: Do you mean you have a hard space? Then use `preg_replace("/>\s>/u",">>>>", $s);`. If there can be more than 1 whitespace between `>`s, add `+` after `\s`. If you do not want to match `>`, linebreak char, `>`, replace `\s` with `\h`.

Comment: Yes I think its a hard space but still the above won't find the arrows

Comment: Please paste your string into http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/ utility and check the spaces you need to find. Are they regular spaces with the decimal code `32`? Anyway, `/>\s>/u` will match all kinds of Unicode spaces (and regular ones, too).

Answer (score 0):

```
$input_lines = "I have a string which has '> >'. I am trying";
echo preg_replace("/(?<!> )> >(?!\s*>)/", "-----", $input_lines);
```

output will be : 
I have a string which has '----'. I am trying

preg_replace(REG_PATTERN, REPLACEMENT, INPUT_STRING); return the desired output.

it will work with any string having '> >', or you might have double space in your string, you can replace that either by increasing space between > and > in regex expression.
 happy coding.